# Haskell: Difference between "(Int a, Bool b) => a -> b" and Int -> Bool

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

The following works fine:

```
isLeap :: Int -> Bool
isLeap x = mod x 4 == 0 && mod x 100 /= 0 || mod x 400 == 0
```

But this one gives me an error:

```
isLeap :: (Int a, Bool b) => a -> b
isLeap x = mod x 4 == 0 && mod x 100 /= 0 || mod x 400 == 0
```

And the error is as follows:

```
app.hs:5:12: error:
    • Expected kind ‘* -> Constraint’, but ‘Int’ has kind ‘*’
    • In the type signature: isLeap :: (Int a, Bool b) => a -> b
  |
5 | isLeap :: (Int a, Bool b) => a -> b
  |            ^^^^^

app.hs:5:19: error:
    • Expected kind ‘* -> Constraint’, but ‘Bool’ has kind ‘*’
    • In the type signature: isLeap :: (Int a, Bool b) => a -> b
  |
5 | isLeap :: (Int a, Bool b) => a -> b
  |                   ^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

I am unable to follow what the line `Expected kind ‘* -> Constraint’, but ‘Bool’ has kind ‘*’` means?

Comment: The part before the `=>` are type constraints. `(Show a)` requires `Show` to be a *typeclass*: a *collection* of types, not a type. The part after the `=>` is a type, so there you need types like `Int` and `Bool`.

Comment: `*` (usually spelled `Type` now) and `Constraint` are both different *kinds* (the concept above types in the type hierarchy). The things on the left of the `=>` must have kind `Constraint`. Type classes have kind `Type -> Constraint`, which means they can be applied to other types to produce `Constraint`s. `Int` and `Bool` both have kind `Type`, not kind `Type -> Constraint`.